# ViewState updated/changed when part of page rendered

Tags: jsf, render, view-scope

My code looks like this:

```
<h:panelGroup id="panelA" > 

        <h:panelGroup id="panelB" rendered="#{!bean.editEnabled}"> 
            <h:outputText value="#{bean.valueA}" styleClass="readOnlyBox wide hasButton" />
            <a4j:commandLink title="edit" action="#{bean.setEditingModeToTrue}"
                    styleClass="icon edit" render="panelA">
            </a4j:commandLink>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup id="panelC" rendered="#{bean.editEnabled}">
            <h:inputText  value="#{bean.valueA}" styleClass="input wide" validatorMessage="Error">
                    <f:validateLength maximum="80"/>
                    <f:validateRegex pattern=".*\\&lt;[^>]+>.*"/>
            </h:inputText>
            <a4j:commandLink title="save" action="#{bean.doValueSave}" 
                styleClass="icon save" render="panelA">
            </a4j:commandLink>
        </h:panelGroup>

</h:panelGroup>
```

Problem occurs when I click on link save. Then linked method is not called. Bean has a view scope and I guess that when I click on edit button (that is required in order to make field editable) then view state is lost so that when I click on save button nothing happends. Am I right? Is there any workaround for this problem? Bean must to have view scope... :/

Comment: Is your panelGroup within a form?

Comment: Yes it is, I forgot to add that in desc...sorry...

Comment: Could you post bean code?